# String preallocation in numpy.arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'])
>>> a[1] = 'thirteen'
>>> print a
['zero' 'thirt' 'two' 'three']
>>>
```

As you can see, the second element has been truncated to the maximum number of characters in the original array.

Is it possible to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't know the maximum length element, then you can use dtype=object

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)
>>> a[1] = 'thirteen'
>>> print a
['zero' 'thirteen' 'two' 'three']
>>>
```

Comment: But then you lose the performance advantages of having an allocated contigous block of memory so you may as well use a python list.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dtype` argument in `numpy.array`, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'], dtype='S8')
>>> a[1] = 'thirteen'
>>> print(a)
['zero' 'thirteen' 'two' 'three']
```